# Detect (find) string in another string ( nvarchar (MAX) )

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I've got nvarchar(max) column with different values alike 'A2'

And another column from another table with values alike '(A2 AND A3) OR A4'

I need to detect does string from second column contains string from first column.

So then I need to select all columns of second table which contains an string from first column of first table.

something alike ... but that is wrong

```
SELECT * Cols FROM T2
WHERE (SELECT T1.StringCol FROM T1) IN T2.StringCol
```

but I more understand it like it (in f# syntax)

```
for t1.date, t1.StringCol from t1
 for t2.StringCol from t2
  if t2.StringCol.Contains( t1.StringCol )
    yield t2.StringCol, t1.date
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get what you want...

```
select t2.*
from t1 cross join t2
where patindex('%' + t1.StringCol + '%', t2.StringCol) > 0
```